# Material UI tooltip popper fixed position on increased word length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, css-selectors

[image]

I want to achieve the above image feature by overriding the MUI tooltip properties but instead, I am only able to get this feature

[image]

I was able to do that by adding a margin to the popper

```
popper: {
  zIndex: '999999999',
  '&[x-placement*="right"]': {
    marginTop: theme.typography.pxToRem(50),
  },
},
```

But after I decrease the word length, it shifts to the bottom of the component where the tooltip was added.

[image]

Please help me achieve this feature. I want the popper position to be fixed when the word length increases and only the height of the popper goes on increasing downwards based on the increased word length.

Answer (score 0):

About your question, I think you could remove the popper style setting and you can try to add placement on the popper that to fixed position.

```js
<Popper placement='right-start'>
.....
...
..
</Popper>
```